# Load native C++ .dll from RAM in debugger friendly manner

Tags: c++, dll, native

Question concerns only Windows for now - other OS's are not so relevant right now.

Just by quick googling - it's possible to load native .dll from RAM, there are for example following libraries:

https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/

=>

https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule

https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/7943

But all of them requires:

1. in-depth knowledge of PE file format
2. mostly those approaches are not debugger friendly.

What I have checked - windows's `LoadLibraryA` / `LoadLibraryW` are directed to `ntdll.dll / LdrLoadDll` - and best picture of how things works can be found from here: https://github.com/hlldz/RefleXXion

And even thus I don't have windows source code - I've checked same functionality from Wine:

LdrLoadDll: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#3169

load_dll: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#3083

load_native_dll:
https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#2564

NtMapViewOfSection: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/unix/virtual.c#4469

find_dll_file: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#3021

open_dll_file: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ntdll/loader.c#2467

Suspect loading dll happens via following function calls:
`NtOpenFile`, `NtQueryAttributesFile`, `NtCreateSection`/`NtOpenSection`, `NtMapViewOfSection` (*)

(More information could be found in

https://github.com/Hagrid29/PELoader

https://gist.github.com/bats3c/59932dfa1f5bb23dd36071119b91af0f

https://www.octawian.ro/fisiere/situri/asor/build/html/_downloads/122f95f9a032396603a837c53b125bb8/Russinovich_M_WinInternals_part1_7th_ed.pdf
)

I was also thinking if I could just override `NtOpenFile` and just redirect file open (in
https://github.com/SegaraRai/PathRedirector manner)
to different path - but main question what is the alternative location where to store file?

I was thinking if NtOpenFile can open even device, then maybe just replace file
with some sort of named pipe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client) - but then in maps on how well this will work with NtMapViewOfSection.

Since I was not able to find any working example of such hook or operation (E.g. `LoadLibary("\\.\pipe\mynamedpipe_as_dll")`) - there is always a risk that such combination is not simply supported.

Is it possible to load native .dll purely from RAM:

1. Without using file system (not to store .dll e.g. in temporary folder)
2. Without involving custom drivers (like Dokan) ?
3. So loaded .dll would be still debugger friendly ?
4. Not tightly bound to PE file format structures (or use PE structures as less as possible)

If you miss bit more information, check also my own experiments with native dll loading (maybe can give some hints on solving the issue):

https://github.com/tapika/test_native_dll_loading
https://github.com/tapika/test_native_dll_loading/discussions/2

Comment: What's the bigger problem? Do you want to debug dynamically generated code? Why the desire to avoid saving the temporary file? The built-in loader relies on the library being backed by a file (not a stream) - something you can memory-map and run the paging logic against.

Comment: I want to have readytorun one executable at the end which can load .dll into ram. Temporary file because I want to avoid antiviruses etc checking the file.

Comment: Will it be running on your machine, or on someone else's?

Comment: Please provide a wider context. Since you mention ReadyToRun - is .NET involved? I sense [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Target is to run it on any windows (7, 8, 10...), 7 maybe not so important, but others are.

Comment: Originated from this ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61073 
Kinda XY problem indeed, as I want to get compression algorithm inside, but trying to solve native dlls embedding. :)

Comment: Distinguish between debug and release use cases. In debug, save the DLL in a temp file and load with LoadLibrary, which will enable debugging. In release, run from memory with no capability for debugging.

Comment: I think if we make initial solution somehow working (non-complex solution), then Microsoft could finish remaining issues. If for example .pdb would not be loaded by vs debugger, then that can be omitted. But main reason why not to create .dll in file system - is for example antivirus software which might detect dll as a virus.

Comment: The underlying issue is all about extracting user code (executables, primarily) into a local folder. What's one more DLL?

Comment: I recommend to convert some of your comments into answer, as I might need to choose one of answers to give bounty away.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish between debug and release use cases. In debug, save the DLL in a temp file and load with LoadLibrary, which will enable debugging. In release, run from memory with no capability for debugging.

Here's another idea, from considering the linked Guthub issue. If the purpose is to let the users provide their own compression/decompression logic while building a ReadyToRun executable, let them provide that as a *static* library (object) as opposed to a DLL. The larger project is already about packaging stuff into a single executable, might do some linking while at it.

Yet another idea would be to let the users provide the codec in some kind of interpreted language and optionally plug in the interpreter that supports debugging. Windows comes with a built-in JavaScript interpreter, look up Active Scripting, and debugging those is a free bonus. The performance probably won't be on par with a native code implementation, though.

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't many answers. But decided to give you bounty, as no better option. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Interpreted language is probably bit overkill - as ReadyToRun file size is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably do something similar with Frida. Hook the functions LoadLibraryA / LoadLibraryW and reimplement them in Frida. but I don't believe this is something that would be stable for production.

[For some reference](https://securityintelligence.com/posts/windows-features-dll-sideloading/)

Comment: Frida is based on some Vala programming language, maybe difficult to integrate as other code is either C++ or C#.

Comment: Frida is not something you would have to integrate into the existing code. It would run in a separate process and as long as the LoadLibraryA/W is called after Frida is hooked into the main process, you would get a callback/hook in the Frida process. the callback i believe you could write in either C++ or JavaScript. This is where you could load a different DLL or load an in memory object into the main process.

Answer (score 1):

By analyzing existing approaches (like `PE Loader` https://github.com/Hagrid29/PELoader) and using `minhook` library - I've managed to load `.dll` from RAM.

I've created git repository with example code on github:

https://github.com/tapika/dllloader

Answer (score -1):

Could you create a ramdisk to put your DLL there? What exactly is the use-case for this? There are a couple ways to spin up a file in RAM, C#'s MemoryMappedFile for example. I'm not sure if this would be debugger friendly.

Comment: Basically in ram loaded .dll's would be loaded by single executable file - readytorun, which in a turn will load all native .dll's. Readytorun .exe file normally is shipped with multiple .pdb files in same folder, this would allow to debug dll even if it's inside executable.