# Execute an executable program (.exe) from memory in Java

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, jna

I want to execute a program in memory on Windows. I do not want to write the file to disk. I just want to pass in a byte array (which is the program I want to execute) as a parameter.

I am not skilled enough to write the native code to do this. Again, this should be Windows native.

The program I want to execute in memory is not a Java program. It is an executable (.exe)! The executable is meant to be read and run IN MEMORY, not through *Runtime.getRuntime().exec("example.exe");*

Comment: Practically impossible, I'd say. SOme motivation?

Comment: Why is Runtime.exec() unsuitable?

Comment: The file I am trying to run will flag a false-positive, for sure, with antivirus software.

Comment: That sounds really safe... there's a reason antivirus software flags executable files. They don't do it "for fun".

Comment: As a novice, you want to do something which expert developers who decades of experience in security try very hard to ensure you can't do? I would suggest you try off your anti-virus software or try something else. You have a better chance of become the President of the USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet, otherwise I would.  You should be able to find some useful information here, where people are trying to solve the same problem using C++.  Pray tell, are you trying to write a program that is cross platform, or Windows only?  Your use of the ".exe" indicates windows only.

[CreateProcess from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305203/createprocess-from-memory-buffer)

You should theoretically be able to make this work by using Windows API calls, as long as you aren't trying to make this cross platform.

Comment: I am only trying to make this for Windows. I am not very experienced with any other language other than Java.

Comment: @Thomas: yeah, not going to happen. Time to move on to your next more *realistic* requirement.