# Execute exe stored in a byte array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, exe, bytestream

I am trying to write a java program which will receive an exe as byte stream and store it in a byte array and this byte array should be executed directly.

The byte array cannot be written to a file because the java program is being run on a system booted from the pen drive.

Update 1: The system is used for a variety of purposes by running different executables and all of them cannot be stored on the machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029111/read-exe-file-in-memory-and-execute-it, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory

Comment: You can't run it from a byte array. It needs to be a file. I don't understand your reasoning for why you can't save it to a file. Even a system with no hard disk should have a RAM drive for temporary files, and you can write the file there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11087612/2078908 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/305203/2078908