# Does Windows supports running a program from memory?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have found out that you can run a program from memory in Windows. But is this functionality considered to be a hack (that could one day not work anymore), or does Windows supports this functionality?

This is one thread that talks about this subject:
[CreateProcess from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305203/createprocess-from-memory-buffer)

Comment: If you need to run a program from memory, consider saving it to a .exe and then running the program. This is much more safer and is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @LHLaurini: How is it safer? Whether you run malware from memory, or save it to disk first, doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @IInspectable "safer" = "guaranteed to work in future versions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not support running processes from memory, only from file. Running processes from memory is a hack that relies on undocumented implementation details which are subject to change. In other words, MS could perfectly well change the system design in a future OS release such that existing run from memory code stopped working.